# Stack and Queue Palindrome Program

Tags: c++, string, queue, stack, palindrome

I am writing a program to determine if a user-entered string of characters is a palindrome.  The program compiles, however when output is printed, all strings of characters are determined to be palindromes even if they are not. I read my textbook varies times, reviewed and debugged the code dozens of times, looked at other similar palindrome questions, but I am still lost.

My code is as follows:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stack>
    #include <queue>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main (void)
    {
      stack <char> s;
      queue <char> q;
      string letter;
      int length;

      cout<<"Please enter a series of characters."<<endl;
      getline (cin, letter);
      length = letter.size();

      for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
          q.push(i);
          s.push(i);
        }

         bool isPalindrome = true;
         while (isPalindrome==true && (!s.empty() && !q.empty()))
         {
           if (s.top() != q.front())
            {
              isPalindrome = false;
            }
          else
           {
            q.pop();
            s.pop();
           }
         }

       if(isPalindrome==false && (s.empty() && q.empty()))
         {
          cout<<"True or false: "<<isPalindrome<<endl;
          cout<<"Is not a palindrome."<<endl;
         }
       else
         {
           cout<<"Is a palindrome."<<endl;
         }

    }
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain why this is happening.  Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you push "letter[i]" instead of "i"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, you push integers instead of characters. To push the characters in the string use `q.push(letters[i])` instead of `q.push(i)`.

You can also get rid of the stack and push half of the string to the queue and then compare it to the other half. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
  queue <char> q;
  string letter;
  int length;

  cout<<"Please enter a series of characters."<<endl;
  getline (cin, letter);

  bool isPalindrome = false;

  if (letters.size() > 0)
  {
    int length = letter.size() / 2;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
      q.push(letters[i]);
    }

    isPalindrome = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= length && isPalindrome; ++i)
    {
      isPalindrome = q.front() == letters[letters.size() - i];
      q.pop();
    }
  }

  if(!isPalindrome)
  {
    cout<<"Is not a palindrome."<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"Is a palindrome."<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Or you can actually just avoid heavy data structures for such a simple task and use a simple loop to do this:

```
bool isPalindrome = false;
int len = letters.size();

if (len > 0)
{
  isPalindrome = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < len / 2 && isPalindrome; ++i)
  {
    isPalindrome = letters[i] == letters[len - i - 1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! The top part about pushing an integer instead of a char and the last if statement solved the problem. Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!! (:

Answer (score 5):

This condition

```
   if(isPalindrome==false && (s.empty() && q.empty()))
```

can be equal to true never.:)

because you set isPalindrome to false in the loop without popping corresponding elements from the stack and queue

```
       if (s.top() != q.front())
        {
          isPalindrome = false;
        }
```

Thus the program control always is passed to else statement

```
   else
     {
       cout<<"Is a palindrome."<<endl;
     }
```

Instead of the wrong condition in the if statement

```
   if(isPalindrome==false && (s.empty() && q.empty()))
```

you could write either

```
   if (isPalindrome == false )
```

or simply

```
   if ( !isPalindrome )
```

or you could remove entirely varaible isPalindrome and use condition

```
   if ( s.empty() && q.empty() )
```

or simpler

```
   if ( s.empty() )
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::string letters;
        std::cout << "Please enter a string (Enter - exit): ";
        std::getline( std::cin, letters );

        if ( letters.empty() ) break;

        std::stack<char> 
            s( std::stack<char>::container_type( letters.begin(), letters.end() ) );
        std::queue<char> 
            q( std::queue<char>::container_type( letters.begin(), letters.end() ) );

        while ( !s.empty() && s.top() == q.front() )
        {
            s.pop();
            q.pop();
        }

        if ( s.empty() ) std::cout << "The string is a palindrome" << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "The string is not a palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! I am beginning to understand what you mean.  I changed my code, but now I did just the opposite and have all user-entered strings of characters printing out that they are not palindromes even if they. Can you please explain more if possible? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jvi1021 you don't need to check both containers. *You just filled them both with identical data.* And since there is no chance of popping from one without the other (which you're also controlling), you can simply check *one* for empty state (which one makes no difference). Further, if you simply break the loop on a mismatch the results of your palindrome check are reflected in the empty condition of either container. I.e. if `s` (or `q`) is empty it is a palindrome, otherwise it isn't. [See it live](http://ideone.com/eKDjdl)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you for all of your help! I greatly appreciate it! (:

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for all of your help! I greatly appreciate it! (:

Answer (score 0):

In the last `if` statement, you are unnecessarily checking if the stack/queue are empty because they most likely wont be if `isPalindrome` was made false above.

Also, looks like you want to put

```
cout<<"True or false: "<<isPalindrome<<endl;
```

before the `if` statement so that it always runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stack>
#include<queue>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
queue<char> q;
stack <char> s;
string name;
int count = 0;
cout << "Please enter a name " << endl;
cin >> name;
for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
    q.push(name[i]);
    s.push(name[i]);
}
bool check = true;
if (!q.empty() && !s.empty() && check){
    if (s.top() == q.front()) {
        q.pop();
        s.pop();
        cout << " It is a palindrome " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << " It's not a palindrome" << endl;

    }

system("pause");
return 0;


}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your code, or as to what are the issues with the previous code (by @jvi1021)